# "beef noodles" and "chicken fried rice"

Tags: culture, food

I've noticed that some native speakers of English find "beef noodles" okay, but others think it's Chinglish. For those who think it is odd, does "chicken fried rice" sound odd too?

Is there a uniform explanation for people's acceptance or rejection of these terms?

Comment: The question is for those who reject "beef noodles" in the first place.

Comment: Can you give a source for your statement that native speakers find beef noodles odd?

Comment: Only some speakers do. Are you a native speaker?

Comment: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/beef-noodles-or-the-noodles-with-beef.3325990/   A user said, "It certainly sounds like Chinglish to me. It may be well-established Chinglish within the context of talking about this dish, but Chinglish nonetheless."

Comment: I had beef noodles last night. Also egg fried rice.

Comment: I'm voting to close because you seem to have already decided what answer you want to get.

Comment: I'm asking for comments from those who find "beef noodles" odd.

Comment: @ThePhoton it's a shame because I mistakenly thought there was a decent question lurking here and put quite a bit of effort into my answer. As you say, the OP isn't looking for an English grammar answer - they are fishing for some kind of opinion-based answer from people who "think" something sounds funny. I certainly won't be answering their questions again after this.

Comment: @Apollyon That would be an opinion. Opinion-based questions are off-topic here. You've asked 408 questions on this site but only accepted answers on 95 of them. I actually think you should be banned from this site, because if you think you know better than native speakers 77% of the time then frankly your questions are a waste of time and are just filling the site with misdirection and wrong information.

Comment: @Apollyon I've also just seen that you've asked a virtually identical question elsewhere on the site. Are you deliberately trolling?? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/266659/minced-pork-rice-or-braised-pork-rice

Comment: @Astralbee Just because you are incapable of thinking in grammatical terms does not mean people are trolling. Let me remind you that a number of Americans also find "minced pork rice" and "beef noodles" odd. They are also native speakers, aren't they?

Answer (score 2):

'Chinglish' is used to describe phrases that have been literally translated from the Chinese language into English, perhaps retaining the original structure, or having some idiomatic meaning in the original language which is lost in translation. Similar terms exist for other languages.

The examples that you gave are the *names* of dishes, not really phrases, so I don't see them as examples of 'Chinglish'. Further, I don't see anything unusual about "beef noodles" or "chicken fried rice". Perhaps you imagine it sounds like the noodles are made out of beef and that it should be "beef *with* noodles"?

There are plenty of similar examples of western cuisine where the names follow this structure. For example "raisin toast" is not toast made exclusively out of raisins - it is toast made from bread with raisins. We also have "cheese scones" - scones made *with* cheese added for flavour. There are American dishes such as "chicken fried steak" (steak fried in the style of fried chicken - it's not even chicken) or "buttermilk chicken" (chicken soaked in buttermilk before cooking). There really is nothing strange to an English speaker about "beef noodles" or "chicken fried rice".

Given that the examples you cite are widely used by English speakers, and that there are countless other traditional British and American dishes with names that defy grammar or structure, anyone native English speaker who says (as you claim some do) that they sound 'odd' is stating an opinion and not one grounded in English grammar.

Comment: "raisin toast" is a kind of toast, and  "cheese scone" is a kind of scone, but is "beef noodles" a kind of noodles?

Comment: It's a kind of noodle dish, yes.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to find Brits saying "beef noodles" is fine. After all, they even say "macaroni cheese," which for Americans would be "macaroni and cheese."

Comment: I suspect that "noodles" or "rice" have acquired additional meaning as a noodle- or rice- based dish. That is not true for some Americans.

Comment: @Apollyon I'm British. Yes we do find it odd that Americans say "macaroni **and** cheese", but that clearly isn't a strict structure - they say "blueberry pancakes", not "pancakes with blueberries".

Comment: "blueberry pancakes" makes sense because it is a kind of pancake, just as "apple pie" is a kind of pie.

Comment: But "macaroni cheese" is not a kind of cheese.

Comment: @Apollyon I think you're looking for something that isn't there. Nouns are sometimes inexplicable. Why is it macaroni cheese, not cheese macaroni? Why does the flavour go second when it goes first in cheeseburger? The entire thing is a **noun**. "Vegetable rice" is a Chinese dish popular here in England. We know it doesn't mean rice made out of vegetables - it's a dish incorporating vegetables *and* rice. Likewise, your dishes are just ones that *contain* noodles.

Comment: "Vegetable rice" sounds like a direct translation from Chinese. Maybe Brits are used to it.

Comment: British English is more relaxed than American English in this regard.

Comment: @Apollyon I completely disagree with that sweeping generalisation. Please do some research - I've just googled 'vegetable rice' and limited the results to USA websites - there are loads of hits. The names of dishes become idiomatic over time. 'Cauliflower Rice' for example **is** actually a dish where grated cauliflower is substituted for rice, but you'd just have to have that knowledge, there is no strict naming convention for dishes. Bye for now.

Comment: There are many ethnic Chinese people who run restaurants in the US, so I wouldn't be surprised to find such uses. But generally, standard American English does not allow formations of that sort.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Lemon cheese doesn't contain cheese either. I suspect the word is used in the sense of 'a semi-solid substance made from lemon juice', like cheese is made from milk.

Comment: "X fried rice" is acceptable in AmE because any "X fried rice" is a kind of fried rice, whether X is pork, chicken, ham, etc.

Comment: Brits seem to allow "rice" and "noodles" to refer to dishes based on them by extension. In this sense BrE is more relaxed than AmE and rather like Chinese.